# unresolved dependency: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.13.0: not found

Tags: sbt-assembly

Did lots of search, saw many people having the similar issue and tried various suggested solution. None worked.

Can someone help me?

```
resolvers += Resolver.url("bintray-sbt-plugins", url("http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.13.0")
```

The file is inside the project folder.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 0.13.0 version, I used 0.14.0 version.

I fixed this by adding POM file which I downloaded from 
    https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.eed3si9n/sbt-assembly/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.14.4/ivys/

to my local ivy folder under below location .ivy/local ( if not present, create the local folder).

once it was there I ran the build and it downloaded the jar.

Comment: I get 'forbidden' when I try following this link.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `[root_dir]/project/plugins.sbt` file with the following content:

```
// packager 
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.5")
```

Event better - **don't use** sbt-assembly at all! Flat-jars cause conflicts during merging which need to be resolved with assemblyMergeStrategy.
Use the **binary distribution** format plugin that sbt offers which enables you to distribute in binary script, dmg, msi and tar.gz.

Check out [sbt-native-packager](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager)